# Trying to return a variable inside a function to call from another function

Tags: function, variables, return

I am trying to return the variable "decimal_degrees" inside the def "DMS_to_DD_calculations(x)"

I then want to assign that variable to test (I tried assigning it as d) so I can use the value of decimal_degrees in def "test(d)"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():

    print "Welcome to the Forward and Back Bearing Calculator"
    print "This program displays the back bearing of a given bearing"
    print ""
    print "How to use:"
    print "Type in the value for the bearing then press enter"
    print ""
    print "Example:"
    print "To enter a bearing the following bearing 33°","15'",'22.5"',"would be entered as 33.15225"
    print ""
    print "The entered bearing will be converted to a back bearing and the result displayed"
    print ""

    user_input= float(raw_input("DMS bearing:"))

    DMS_to_DD_calculations(user_input)
    decimal_degrees = test(d)

def DMS_to_DD_calculations(x):
    #These 3 functions assign an individual value for the variables: Degrees (d), Minutes (m) and Seconds (s) for the given bearing
    # 1. Degrees is equal to the integer value of the user entered bearing
    d= int(x)

    # 2. Minutes:
    #       First - Find the user entered value minus the integer of that value times 100.
    #       Second - The integer of THAT value is the minutes
    no_int_m= (x-int(x))*100
    int_m= int(no_int_m)
    m= int_m

    # 3. Seconds:
    #       First -  Find the user entered value minus the integer of that value times 100
    #       Second - Minus the integer of THAT value is the seconds
    s= (no_int_m-int_m)*100

    decimal_degrees= (((s/60)+m)/60)+d

    print ""
    print "DD BEARING =", decimal_degrees,"°"
    return decimal_degrees

def test(d):
    print "yes"
    if decimal_degrees > 0:
        print "success"

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line `return decimal_degrees` in `DMS_to_DD_calculations`, you enable `decimal_degrees` to be assigned to a variable outside of the function (e.g. `dec_degrees = DMS_to_DD_calculations(x)`)

Then `dec_degrees` (or whatever you named the variable) can be passed into the function `test`

Since there is no return value for the function `test`, the line `decimal_degrees = test(d)` will return `None`.

Also, because decimal_degrees is not a global variable, its name would need to be changed to `d` as is the parameter name in `test`

Comment: I still don't get how to do this sorry, could you provide an example?

Comment: this line: `DMS_to_DD_calculations(user_input)` needs to be updated to receive the `decimal_degrees` variable returned. Try: `decimal_degrees = DMS_to_DD_calculations(user_input)`. Then `decimal_degrees` can be passed into `test` like this: `test(decimal_degrees)`. However, in your `test` function, the variable name is d, which it looks like is supposed to represent decimal_degrees. If so, the line `if decimal_degrees > 0:` in `test` would need to be updated to be: `if d > 0:`

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark

Comment: Awesome! took me a while to understand but I got there, thanks heaps!